# force react native (Android) app to update

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, in-app

I'm getting ready to put my application in the play store but I need your help about force user to update if I put another new version.

After searching I found two approaches:

1. `react-native-version-check` library: I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kinley.tshering/force-update-react-native-apps-a9c1f22c0701)
2. `react-native-android-inapp-updates` library

I don't know which lib to choose but I think the first approach (react-native-version-check) is better.

What do you think? Are there any other (better) suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a shameless plug here. I am one of the maintainers for react-native-android-inapp-updates.

react-native-android-inapp-updates is a wrapper around the [official android  in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)!.

[Here is the library in action within our production app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bAgu.gif)

With this library, you dosen't need to mantain your own "versioning" system because we rely on Google Play Store.

For your usecase if you decided to use our library i suggest you to use the `Immediate` type for IAP. Immediate type will enable A full screen user experience that requires the user to update and restart the app in order to continue using the app. This UX is best for cases where an update is critical for continued use of the app. After a user accepts an immediate update, Google Play handles the update installation and app restart.

Comment: You can tell how can I test it before publish my app in play store ?

Comment: any syggestion please ? you can give me an example how to implemente it ?